# Runtime error 91: Object Variable or With Block Variable not set on ActiveSheet.Range.Top

Tags: excel, vba

I have been running this code for months. Suddenly the code is breaking on

```vb
.Top = rngCell.Top
```

giving me

> Runtime error 91: Object Variable or With Block Variable not set

[image]

```vb
    sFileName = Dir(strInitialFolder & "*.pdf") 
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0 
        If Right(sFileName, 3) = "pdf" Then 
            Select Case Left(sFileName, 3) 
                Case "HCM" 
                    Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B25") 
                    sCaption = "HCM_Summary_PDF" 
                Case "CTS" 
                    Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C25") 
                    sCaption = "CTS_Summary_PDF" 
            End Select
            Set objOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strInitialFolder & sFileName, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _ 
                IconFileName:=icoPDF, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=sFileName) 
            
            With objOLE 
                .name = sCaption 
                .Top = rngCell.Top 
                .Left = rngCell.Left '.Verb 
            End With 
        End If
     'Set the fileName to the next available file
            sFileName = Dir
        Loop
```

Code working
[image: Good image-code working]

Code breaks and leaves the first pdf way at the bottom out of place
[image: Bad image-code breaks and leaves the first pdf way at the bottom out of place]

Comment: Could you post your code as text please rather than an image.  By the looks of it there's a problem with how `rngCell` is defined, but that's hidden behind the error message.  Could be that `ActiveSheet` isn't the sheet you're expecting, or a number of other things. [mcve]

Comment: Sorry about the image! I have pasted the code below:

Comment: 'add new ones
    sFileName = Dir(strInitialFolder & "*.pdf")
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        If Right(sFileName, 3) = "pdf" Then
            Select Case Left(sFileName, 3)
                Case "HCM"
                    Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("B25")
                    sCaption = "HCM_Summary_PDF"
                Case "CTS"
                    Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Range("C25")
                    sCaption = "CTS_Summary_PDF"
            End Select

Comment: Set objOLE = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strInitialFolder & sFileName, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                    IconFileName:=icoPDF, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=sFileName)
            
            With objOLE
                .name = sCaption
                .Top = rngCell.Top
                .Left = rngCell.Left
                '.Verb
            End With
        End If

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't seem to format the code properly. It looks clearly laid out when I paste it into the comment field, but then after pressing enter it becomes a paragraph. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, should have said you can edit your original question - edit button is just below the tags at the bottom. of the question.

Comment: I take it your code does have the `Loop` to close the `Do While`?  `strInitialFolder & sFileName` is returning a valid file name?

Comment: Hi Darren, yes there is a loop function at the end:

Comment: Hi Darren, yes there is a loop function at the end. I added the rest of the code to the image above. A contractor (a wonderful one at that!) had written this code for me to automate a laborious process. The process takes payroll data which is housed in an Excel document, puts that data into a workbook where it goes through various processes to be audited and compared against pdf report summaries(because the pdf's should tie to the raw data in excel at a summary level - this is just one of multiple internal control checks), and then moves all the data over to a journal entry where it can

Comment: be loaded into the General Ledger. I used to perform all those steps by hand, and she automated all of it by way of two macros. The particular code bit we are seeing here is the part where two pdf payroll summary reports are getting embedded into the payroll workbook. These are the two pdf summaries that should tie to the raw data so we like to include them in the file. It looks to me like the code started to error on the placement of one of the two pdf files, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: To answer your question on strInitialFolder & sFileName, yes these are returning a valid name. I double checked in the immediate window.

Comment: One more comment here, I added 2 pictures - 1st pic is what "should happen" after code runs. Do you see the pdf's embedded at the bottom of the image? That is where they are supposed to go - HCM on the left and CTS on the right, in order for HCM to line up underneath the HCM data. In this example there is no CTS data and the CTS pdf report is actually empty, but we still need to put it in there so an auditor can open it and see it is empty. So, the code is now erroring at the point when it is trying to place the first pdf document into the spreadsheet, which I believe is the CTS pdf by design

Comment: 2nd pic shows what happens with the first pdf document at the point when the code breaks. When the code breaks, and I end it, and look at the spreadsheet to see where the code left off, I see the CTS pdf way down at the bottom of the spreadsheet totally out of place.